# decomposition of general symplectic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Suppse $S$ be a $2n \times 2n $ symplectic matrix $$
 S = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C  & D
\end{array} \right) .
$$

By definition, $S^tJS$=J, where

$$J = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & I\\
-I  & 0
\end{array} \right) .
$$

Now there is a theorem states that $S=S_1S_2$ where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are free symplectic matrices. This means,

$$S_i = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A_i & B_i\\
C_i  & D_i
\end{array} \right), det(B_i)\neq 0.
$$

Now suppose $S$ be symplectic matrix with respect to different skew bilinear form i.e $S^t \theta S=\theta$, where

$$\theta = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & \theta _1\\
-\theta _1^t  & 0
\end{array} \right) .
$$
Is the decomposition of of $S$ into two free symplectic matrices still possible?

Comment: Have you tried generalizing the steps of the proof of the theorem?  Do you have a reference for that theorem which has a proof?

Comment: https://books.google.de/books?id=IT0FMVgvqp4C&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=free+symplectic+matrix&source=bl&ots=0qGwRxI3JR&sig=CrU5iXGP_6SZrUVWdB0pYLHgqPw&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=free%20symplectic%20matrix&f=false